# Problem assigning a Swift function to a function variable

Tags: swift, function, variables

Here is a trivialized example of my problem:

```
class Test: NSObject {
    func metaHandler(name elementName: String, attributes attr : NSDictionary) -> NSNumber
    {
        return NSNumber.init()
    }
    var metaHandlerFunc: ((String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber) = metaHandler
}
```

I get a compiler error when I assign the function to the var:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Test) -> (String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber' to specified type '(String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber'
```

My example seems to be exactly what I have seen illustrated elsewhere. Any suggestions?

I'm running Xcode 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `metaHandler` as an *instance* method, i.e. as a method which is applied to a concrete instance of `Test`. As such it has the signature

```
(Test) -> (String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber
```

see for example [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

Defining it as a “type method” (with `class` or `static`) solves the problem:

```
static func metaHandler(...)
```

Now it has the signature `(String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber` and can be assigned to `var metaHandlerFunc`.

Choose `class func` if overriding the method in a subclass should be allowed.

Comment: While this is true, the problem (at least when I am running the provided example) reported is that "property initializers run before 'self' is available". So a `lazy var` seems to solve the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alladinian: You are right, that would solve the compiler error as well (feel free to post as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to assign an instance function to an instance variable, which means that the instance *should* be initialized before assignment.

Btw the error I get (Swift 5.2.4) is:

> cannot use instance member 'metaHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

which is a lot more helpful and can be solved by making `metaHandlerFunc` `lazy`:

```
lazy var metaHandlerFunc: ((String, NSDictionary) -> NSNumber) = metaHandler
```

alternatively, you can make the function static as stated in Martin's answer.